# How to insert scripts in an asp.net mvc c# project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I create a default mvc asp.net c# project, on _layout.cshtml inside the body tag there is the Render.Body() and before the closing of the body there are the script bundles for jquery and bootstrap. When I try to write a script in my View, it says that jQuery is not defined. That's obvious because the script bundles get called after the Render.Body(). So I'm asking the silly question. Is it wrong to move the bundles above the Render.Body()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a 'section' to your `_Layout` file then the View can inject into it. This will ensure the script runs *after* jquery is available.

Try this:

**Layout**

Add this under the jquery (and other) scripts in there:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

**Views**

Then in any view you want to add some script do the following:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
    //do stuff here
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dependency scripts such as jQuery are loaded after those that require them, you need to move them above. You can do this, as you suggested, by moving the jQuery bundle above the body or, depending on the structure of your application, including the jQuery at the start of your script bundle.

There are likely other methods to get around this problem but I have not used them. It is not 'wrong' to put scripts above the body, it just has different advantages and disadvantages compared to other options.